# Drush how to sync Database to remote server?

Tags: drush

I already use `drush rsync @self @a` push the local file to remote server.

this following is my .drushrc file:

```
$aliases['a'] = array(
  'remote-host' => '115.28.132.217',
  'remote-user' => 'root',
  'root' => '/var/www/daxuebao',
);
```

I try to run this following command to sync database.

```
$ drush sql-sync @self @a
```

But throw me an error:

```
Error: no alias record could be found for target @a                  [error]
```

How to solve it ?

Comment: Trust your error messages: add an alias.

http://deeson-online.co.uk/labs/drupal-drush-aliases-and-how-use-them

Comment: I'am sorry, I updated my question

Comment: I add the alais file, and the error diffrent.

Comment: Again, trust your error messages: "drush:command not found". Have you installed drush in the remote system? If yes, I think drush is not int the ssh shell path.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify an alias in a `.drush/aliases.drushrc.php` file:

```
    $aliases['a'] = array(
      'root' => '/path/to/drupal',
      'uri' => 'a.mydrupalsite.com',
    );
```

More info on:

- https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/blob/master/examples/example.aliases.drushrc.php
- http://deeson-online.co.uk/labs/drupal-drush-aliases-and-how-use-them

Comment: I add the alais file, and the error diffrent.

Comment: This is a separate issue and therefore a separate question that requires a different answer.

Comment: @Wooden I've rolled back your latest edit - please stop changing the meaning of questions once they've been asked. You're currently using this site like a personal support forum, and that's not what it is - this a repository of high quality knowledge about Drupal. We can't and won't give you the one-to-one support you seem to be expecting here. Unless your question is likely to be useful to future visitors, and related **directly** to Drupal (as in not about file permissions, server config, spelling mistakes, etc), we can't help you here. I strongly encourage you to read the [help]. Thanks

Comment: Thanks @Wooden - we absolutely do want to help you, but we need to make sure the ethos of the site is upheld at the same time